# How to add onClick in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hello i want to add onClick option in a Fragment to a ImageView.
I tried a few things but failed.
Here is my Fragmet.java

public class Info extends Fragment{

```
public Info() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override

```
  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

and use the `view` object, which is the same `View` you are returning in `onCreateView`, to look for the ImageView on which you want to set your `onClickListener`. E.g.

```
  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.id_of_image_view);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the view directly ,do this

```
View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);
```

you can then use v to find reference to your ImageViews

```
ImageView iv=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageview_id);
```

then set onClickListener as usual

```
iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have an `ImageView` in the `layout R.layout.info.`
If the `ImageView`'s id is `ivInLayout`, you set an `onClik` mehtod like this:

```
public class Info extends Fragment{

    public Info() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViwById(R.id.ivInLayout);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(){
                 <What you want onClick on the image to do>
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

}
```